# Как правильно добавить библиотеку Socket.io к проекту?

Tags: java, android, socket.io

Совсем новичок в Java) сейчас по [туториалам](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) пытаюсь использовать [библиотеку Socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) (использую в Android Studio)
Добавил библиотеку через Project Structure в Dependencies и в самом проекте импортировал классы

```
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Socket mSocket ;
mSocket = IO.Socket('Localhost:8080')
```

Но на последней строке возникает ошибка "Cannot resolve symbol 'Socket'

почему это может происходить?

Comment: если писать      IO.socket с маленькой буквой ошибка всё равно есть)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял свою ошибку)

```
    private Socket mSocket;
{
try {
    mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.100.3:8080");
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
};
```

Вместо

```
private Socket mSocket ;
mSocket = IO.Socket('http://Localhost:8080')
```

Answer (score 2):

Одинарные кавычки на двойные замените

Comment: не помогло, просто когда начинаю писать IO. дальше просто не предлагает именно socket как будто его нету